# MYSQL in Kamailio

Tags: mysql, kamailio

I'm trying to install Kamailio but received this error.
ERROR: database engine not specified, please set up one in the config script.

When I check kamctlrc, I found this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nIqB.png)

My kamctlrc shows DBENGINE=MYSQL. Isn't this already setup?
Anyone knows how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The line you highlighted in the screenshot is commented -- remove the **#** from the start of the line.

kamctlrc is actually interpreted as a shell script, so same syntax applies -- what is a comment in a shell script is a comment in kamctlrc.